# PlayerView is overlapping to each other in ExoPlayer media3 while using in ViewPager2?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, exoplayer, android-media3

I have view horizontal ViewPager2 in which have 2 types of view (separate layouts) image and video.
I have used resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM  and when two video are in next to each other one video is overlapping another view. when using another resize mode it works good however I need RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM.
[image: here is what I have from the left i get overlapped my player]

viewpager:

```
  <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="358dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

in adapter:

```
//.. some code//
    inner class HomePageVimeoViewHolder(private val binding: AppHomepageBoxVimeoItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
//.. some code//

        private lateinit var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer
        @OptIn(UnstableApi::class) private fun initializePlayer(videoUrl: String) {
            exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(mContext).build().apply {
                val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(videoUrl))
                setMediaItem(mediaItem)
                prepare()
                playWhenReady = true  // Autoplay when the player is ready
                repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL
                volume = 0f
            }
            binding.videoView.apply {
                player = exoPlayer
                useController = false  // Disable the ExoPlayer controls
                resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM // Adjust this based on need
            }
        }
//.. some code//
}
```

fragment:

```
//.. some code//
    private fun setupViewPager() {
        homePageAdapter = HomePageAdapter(requireContext(), homePageBoxes)
        homePageAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this)

        binding.pager.offscreenPageLimit = 2
        binding.pager.adapter = homePageAdapter
        binding.indicator.attachTo(binding.pager)

        // Initialize HorizontalSwipeViewPager2 with our ViewPager2 instance
        HorizontalSwipeViewPager2(binding.pager, requireContext())
    }
//.. some code//
```

gradle:

```
//.. some code//
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.2.0'
//.. some code//
```

Comment: have you found a solution, please share with us?

Comment: @KostyaRudenko not yet when I will find solution I will post it for sure, please do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Custom ViewPager2 PageTransformer.

Implement a custom PageTransformer for your ViewPager2 to manage the transformation and spacing of items. Adjust the translation values or scales within the transformer to avoid overlap.

```
viewPager2.setPageTransformer { page, position ->
val normalizedPosition = Math.abs(Math.abs(position) - 1)
page.scaleY = normalizedPosition / 2 + 0.5f
}
```

Please try above solution it's work for Me...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use TextureView:

```
<androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView 
    app:surface_type="texture_view" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this topic in more detail.
and create a bug ticket in the media [one](https://github.com/androidx/media/issues/1107)

my finding helped me to find this solution that might help you.
I just set the surface type to texture and it helped
`app:surface_type="texture_view" />`